# How to unmarshall a file using JAXB having shared references in multiple file (.xml)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

JAXB is used to marshall java objects to a file.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CompleteCollectionInfo {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlID
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
    protected String uid;
}

@XmlRootElement
public class AssociationInfo {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "IDREF")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type= CompleteCollectionInfo.class , value =AssociationCompleteCollectionInfoAdapter.class)
    protected CompleteCollectionInfo associatedcollection;
}
```

Adapter will make sure that the all the CompleteCollectionInfo References if unmarshalled before is set properly in the Association Info

```
public class AssociationCompleteCollectionInfoAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, CompleteCollectionInfo>{

    @Override
    public CompleteCollectionInfo unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {

        CompleteCollectionInfo completeCollectionInfo = UnBlobUtil.completeCollectionCache.get(v);

        if (completeCollectionInfo == null )
            completeCollectionInfo = new CompleteCollectionInfo();

        completeCollectionInfo.setUid(v);

        return completeCollectionInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(CompleteCollectionInfo v) throws Exception {

        return v.getUid();
    }

}
```

**Exception i Get While Marshalling:
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
XmlIDREF property is referencing a type "java.lang.String" that doesn't have an XmlID property.**

Comment: can you post Group.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `XmlAdapter` is telling `JAXB` to treat `CompleteCollectionInfo` as a `String`.  So it is true that `String` doesn't have a property annotated with `@XmlID`.  `@XmlID`/`@XmlIDREF` is for references within a document so it doesn't apply for your use case anyway.

You are already doing the right thing for your use case with `XmlAdapter`.  To get things to work you should just need to remove `@XmlID`/`@XmlIDREF`.

Comment: Thank you @blaise,I understood wat u r trying to say, i will get back to u after implementing

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `JAXBContext` to know how to unmarshal `Student` as well you'll have to do the following:

```
JAXBContext theContext = JAXBContext.newInstance (Group.class, Student.class);
```

Comment: But the student details are stored in a separate file, Cross referecne, even if i do the changes u mentioned it does not work

Comment: can you post both xml files?